Which test do I use for checking chain convergence on an mcmc glmm with a factorial response variable?
I am running an mcmc glmm (mcmc package in R) with the following structure:
continuous response variable + continuous response variable + factorial response variable ~ all of my covariates+etc.
This model is complex, so unless you are familiar with this kind of model let`s pretend the model is:
factorial response variable ~ covariates+etc.
I need to check for chain convergence (I ran 4 chains of this model with different seeds, which I then combined into one list object). When I perform the Gelman diagnostics I overall get good values (for numerical response variables), but for any combination that includes the factorial response variable the diagnostics are not ok (>1.1). I found some sources online, which state that the Gelman diagnostics may not be suitable for discrete/factorial/categorical variables, and tests like the "Weiss procedure" or "Billingsley approach" could be useful. See  arxiv.org/pdf/1706.04919 for more information on this.
My question is: what chain convergence diagnostics are recommended for factorial response variables when running mcmc glmm´s in R, and how do I code them in R?
Thank you for your help!
I tried to find code for the aforementioned alternatives, but only found code for other programming languages.
